# Are the words 이상 and 이하 inclusive?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning

The words 이상 and 이하 can follow a number to mean "more than" or "less than":

> 3년 이상

However, it's not always clear if the number itself is included: does the above mean "more than 3 years" or "3 years or more"?

The dictionary isn't so helpful:

> 이상: 1. 수량이 기준을 포함하면서 그 위인 경우
>   
>  2. 정도가 기준보다 높음

One seems to suggest the amount is included, the other doesn't.  So is it inclusive or not, or ambiguous, or sometimes one sometimes the other?  If it's sometimes one, sometimes the other, how can I tell if the number is included?

Comment: the first meaning is applicable to numbers only, so only when counting. But the second meaning is pointing to intangible things, like 정도. The two meanings can coexist, thus.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy What do you mean by "pointing to intangible things"? Can you show us an example?

Answer (score 8):

이상 and 이하 is always inclusive.

초과 and 미만 is always not inclusive.

Therefore,

3년 이상 is 3 years or more

3년 이하 is 3 years or less

cf.

3년 초과 is more than 3 years

3년 미만 is less than 3 years.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, please leave a comment on how to improve this answer.

Answer (score 3):

"3년 이하의 징역" is translated to "equal to or less than 3 years in prison".

No. 1 definition for '이상' clearly states that "1. 수량이 **기준을 포함**하면서 그 위인 경우" and '이상' definitely includes the number that precedes it.

According to the linked [법률용어사전 on 이상 · 이하 · 초과 · 미만 (以上 · 以下 · 超過 · 未滿)](http://terms.naver.com/entry.nhn?docId=458297&cid=42131&categoryId=42131):

> 일정한 수량을 기준으로 그 기준보다 수량이 많다거나 적다는 것을 나타낼 경우에는 「이상」 · 「이하」 · 「초과」 ·
> 「미만」 등의 용어가 사용되고 있다. 이 중에서도 「이상」과 「이하」는 기준이 되는 일정한 수량을 포함한다는 의미로 사용된다.
> 즉 1만원 **이상**이라고 하면 **1만원과 1만원보다 많은 액수를 포함**하고, 1만원 **이하**라고 하면 **1만원과 1만원보다 적은 액수를
> 포함**하여 나타내는 것이다. 이에 대하여 기준이 되는 수량을 포함하지 않고 많다거나 적다는 것을 나타내려고 할 경우에는 전자에
> 대하여는 「1만원을 초과한다」하고 후자에 대하여는 「1만원 미만」이 라고 하는 것이다.

Brief summary:

> When you say '1만원 이상', it means 1만원 or other amounts bigger than 1만원.
>
> When you say '1만원 이하', it means 1만원 or other amounts smaller than
> 1만원.

If you don't want to include the number, you should use '초과' for '이상' and '미만' for '이하 as follows:

> 1만원 초과 means bigger than 1만원 (excluding 1만원).
>
> 1만원 미만 means smaller than 1만원 (excluding 1만원).